# JSONPath union "[,]" equivalent in GPath

Tags: groovy, jsonpath, gpath

Consider given JSON

```json
{
  "data": {
    "array": [
      {
        "foo": {"a": "1 foo a", "b": "2 foo b", "c": 512},
        "bar": {"a": "3 bar a", "b": "4 bar b"},
        "baz": {"a": "5 baz a", "b": "6 baz b", "d": 75},
        "other": {"a": 2, "x": 13, "y": 44},
      },
      {
        "foo": {"a": "7 foo a", "b": "8 foo b"},
        "bar": {"a": "9 bar a", "b": "10 bar b"},
        "baz": {"a": "11 baz a", "b": "12 baz b"},
        "other": {"a": 2, "x": 13, "y": 44, "z": 132},
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With simple JSONPath I can list all the `a`s and `b`s from the `foo`s, `bar`s and `baz`es in respective order

```
$.data.array[*][foo,bar,baz][a,b]
```

```
[
  "1 foo a", "2 foo b",
  "3 bar a", "4 bar b",
  "5 baz a", "6 baz b",
  "7 foo a", "8 foo b",
  "9 bar a", "10 bar b",
  "11 baz a", "12 baz b"
]
```

Is there any ways to do so using Groovy GPath?
The only working(ish) solution I've come up with is:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)

json.data.array.foo.a
+ json.data.array.foo.b
+ json.data.array.bar.a
+ json.data.array.bar.b
+ json.data.array.baz.a
+ json.data.array.baz.b
```

But result is still differs (in order) from JSONPath

```
[1 foo a, 7 foo a,
 2 foo b, 8 foo b,
 3 bar a, 9 bar a,
 4 bar b, 10 bar b,
 5 baz a, 11 baz a, 
 6 baz b, 12 baz b]
```

#### P.S.

I'm using GPath for my Rest-Assured tests, so if there's alternative to get the same result in Rest-Assured, I'd be glad to see it.

#### P.P.S

Actually I've found another solution

```
json.data.array
    *.subMap(["foo", "bar", "baz"])*.values().flatten()
    *.subMap(["a", "b"])*.values().flatten()
```

Which yields the same result as JSONPath

```
[1 foo a, 2 foo b,
 3 bar a, 4 bar b,
 5 baz a, 6 baz b,
 7 foo a, 8 foo b,
 9 bar a, 10 bar b,
 11 baz a, 12 baz b]
```

But it's still not the alternative for union operation in JSONPath.
For example, there's another, a bit more complex expression:

```
$.data.array[*][foo,bar,?(@.a == '11 baz a')][a,b]
```

The GPath alternative for that one would be nothing like `subMap`
solution above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Xiao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562154/xiao) I've come up with the closest to JsonPath solution:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input) //text is your json string

def result = json.data.array
        .collectMany { [it.foo, it.bar, it.baz] }
        .collectMany { [it.a, it.b] }

println result // [1 foo a, 2 foo b, 3 bar a, 4 bar b, 5 baz a, 6 baz b, 7 foo a, 8 foo b, 9 bar a, 10 bar b, 11 baz a, 12 baz b]
```

However, if I want alternative for

```
$.data.array[*][foo,bar,?(@.a == '11 baz a')][a,b]
```

the result is way more dirty:

```
def result = json.data.array
        .collectMany {
            [it.foo, it.bar] + (it.baz.a == '11 baz a' ? it.baz : [])
        }
        .collectMany { [it.a, it.b] }
```

I think, if we omit usage with filters, `collectMany` can be considered as equivalent for `[,]`.

P.S. Your versions for filtered union are welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pure gpath version to solve your problem, using [collectMany](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collectMany(groovy.lang.Closure)) and [collect](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)) methods:

UPDATED ANSWER according to RomanMitasov's updated question:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(text) //text is your json string
def result = json.data.array*.collectMany{k,v-> k in ["foo","bar","baz"]? v.collect{k1,v1-> k1 in ["a","b"]? v1:[]}:[]}.flatten()
println result //[1 foo a, 2 foo b, 3 bar a, 4 bar b, 5 baz a, 6 baz b, 7 foo a, 8 foo b, 9 bar a, 10 bar b, 11 baz a, 12 baz b]
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(text) //text is your json string
def result = json.data.array*.collectMany{k,v->v.collect{it.value}}.flatten()
println result //[1 foo a, 2 foo b, 3 bar a, 4 bar b, 5 baz a, 6 baz b, 7 foo a, 8 foo b, 9 bar a, 10 bar b, 11 baz a, 12 baz b]
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I provided bad example. `$.data.array[*][foo,bar,baz][a,b]` means I want to process ONLY foo, bar and baz (and only a and b respectively), not just all keys in objects. I'll update my question. Good solution tho, big thanks!